# Render template string with React and allow editing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an email template body (in html) that's generated by a server. The template has a section I'd like to make editable in a React component.  Simplified, the template looks like this:

```
<div class="message">
  <p>Hello!</p>
  <p>Welcome to our app... blah blah</p>
  <div class="user-customisable"></div>
  <p>Yours, app support</p>
</div>
```

In my frontend app, I'd like to render the template as it will appear in the final email (which I can do with `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`), but I'd also like the `user-customisable` div to be editable so the admin can add a custom message.

I need to be able to add a textarea or contenteditable attribute and hook it up to the state but I'm not sure how to go about it, any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If I understand you right, you need to display this HTML as is and only make only `user-customisable` div editable. If so, you can make React component with logic you need and link it to this div using `ReactDOM.render(..., document.querySelector(".message .user-customisable"))`

Comment: If you want to make all of you static `message` div editable, you need to render you React component right into this div (using `ReactDOM.render(..., document.querySelector(".message"))`, but you need to make sure, that your React component generates the same HTML as your static HTML. You can use different isomorpic approaches to make it reliable.

Comment: render these html as children of a component like.. `<SomeComponent>{YourHtml}</SomeComponent>`